# Convert background-size and background-position relative values to absolute PX values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I have a div with a background image, a custom background size (which is auto + %), and a custom background position (which is x% y%).

So I have all this data:

- div width
- div height
- div bg size
- div bg image width
- div bg image height
- div bg image position x
- div bg image position y

For example:

- div width: 200px
- div height: 100px
- div bg size: auto 105%
- div bg image width: 400px
- div bg image height: 280px
- div bg image position x: 20%
- div bg image position y: 12%

I need to convert this to PX values to I can recreate it in a canvas.

When I have all the values, I would do something like:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, sx, sy, swidth, sheight, 100, 100, 200, 100).
```

But I need to clip the image using sx, sy, swidth and sheight which are the starting coordinates of the clipping and and width and height of the clipping.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is converting the percentage background position to the equivalent pixel values. In this example, you do it this way: ((image width - div width) * background percentage). It looks much more complicated when looking at the code but here is a working example:

```js
var testDiv = $("#test");
var bgImgSize = testDiv.css("background-size").replace(/px|%/g, "").split(" ");
var bgImgPosition = testDiv.css("background-position").replace(/px|%/g, "").split(" ");
var bgImgXPosition = (bgImgPosition[0] == 100) ? (bgImgSize[0] - testDiv.width()) : ((bgImgSize[0] - testDiv.width()) * (bgImgPosition[0] * .01));
var bgImgYPosition = (bgImgPosition[1] == 100) ? (bgImgSize[1] - testDiv.height()) : ((bgImgSize[1] - testDiv.height()) * (bgImgPosition[1] * .01));

var props = {
  "divWidth": testDiv.width(),
  "divHeight": testDiv.height(),
  "bgImgWidth": bgImgSize[0],
  "bgImgHeight": bgImgSize[1],
  "bgImgXPosition": bgImgXPosition,
  "bgImgYPosition": bgImgYPosition,
  "bgImg": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/7102/notes-macbook-study-conference.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=280&w=400"
}

var c = document.getElementById("test-canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, props.bgImgXPosition.toFixed(2), props.bgImgYPosition.toFixed(2), props.divWidth, props.divHeight, 0, 0, props.divWidth, props.divHeight);
};
img.src = props.bgImg;
```

```css
#test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/7102/notes-macbook-study-conference.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=280&w=400);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 400px 267px;
  background-position: 20% 12%; /* Original position */ 
  /* Pixel equivalent: background-position: -40px -20.04px;*/
  /* (image width - div width) *  x background position, (image height - div height) *  y background position */ 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
<canvas id="test-canvas" width="200px" height="100"></canvas>
```

You can certainly adjust as necessary given the actual values you'll be working with. I have a div with the background image applied given your example values and then a canvas drawing the same thing with the conditions you're looking for.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uakh6p9b/74/)

Comment: Wow thanks, I actually used html2canvas but this is really useful for a not so overkill situation!

Comment: Glad I could help! I actually updated my code to handle 100% background position values. I found that any value worked except for 100%. It works now though.